# How to add JS event to Dynamically created element by angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have created an angularjs directive which returns 2 divs for which I have animations. When I render the directive on the html page, I am able to see those directives but, I am not able to select the element with id. When I select the element with id, I am getting null value.

How can I resolve this? Here is my snippet.

```js
var application = angular.module('newsfeed', [])

application.directive('newsfeeds', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: `
       <div id="reveal-button"><<</div>
       <div class="reveal-content"></div>
      `
  }
})
var slideContainer = document.getElementById('slide-container'); //selecting the element
var slideButton = document.getElementById('reveal-button'); //selecting the element
var slideopen = false;

console.log(slideButton); //logging the output to console returns null

var showslide = function() {
  slideContainer.style.right = '0px'
}

var hideslide = function() {
  slideContainer.style.right = '-350px'
}

window.addEventListener('slideButton', 'click', function() {
  if (slideopen == false) {
    slideopen = true;
    showslide();
  } else {
    slideopen = false;
    hideslide();
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Where did you put this javascript code? Looks like you're completely ignoring with how you should do this in angular

Answer (score -1):

mention this line to your HTML file.

```js
var slideContainer = document.getElementById('slide-container');//selecting the element
    var application = angular.module('newsfeed',[])

application.directive('newsfeeds',function(){
    return{
        restrict: 'E',
        template:`
            <div id="reveal-button"><<</div>
            <div class="reveal-content"></div>
        `
    }
})
    application.controller('mainController', function($scope,$timeout) {
  var slideButton = document.getElementById('reveal-button'); //selecting the element
    var slideopen = false;

    console.log(slideButton);   //logging the output to console returns null

    var showslide = function(){
        slideContainer.style.right = '0px'
    }

    var hideslide = function(){
        slideContainer.style.right = '-350px'   
    }

    window.addEventListener('slideButton','click',function(){
        if(slideopen == false){
            slideopen = true;
            showslide();    
        } else {
            slideopen = false;
            hideslide();
        }       
    })

  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" ng-app="newsfeed" ng-controller="mainController">
  <newsfeeds></newsfeeds>
</div>
```